# how to check if an array of booleans contains all true values?

Tags: java, arrays, boolean

I have the following boolean array:

```
boolean booleanArray[]  = new boolean [size];
```

How can I check if all values inside the array are true, and use this information for another boolean " allTrue "?

I need to use this for a while loop, i.e.:

```
while(alltrue){
            keepgoing();
        }
```

I thought of doing a for loop checking each value but that just returns the value of one, and I don't know how to compare with the rest to know if they are all equal.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would use a [`BitSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) for this purpose instead of a `boolean[]`. This way, your loop would simplify into `while (myBitSet.cardinality() == size) { keepGoing(); }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize a variable to `true`, and if you find a `false`, set `allTrue` to `false` and `break` out of the loop.

```
boolean allTrue = true;
for (boolean b : booleanArray)
{
    if (!b)
    {
        allTrue = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you really helpfull will acept in 9 min :9